# FireEvent("ondblclick") doesn't work in Firefox 3.6 and QTP11

Tags: qtp

I'm trying to perform double click in Firefox on existing object using QTP 11 and nothing happens.
I turned on even logging in firebug and see, that BlotterObj.FireEvent "onclick" 
 "onclick" even produce "onmousedown", "onmouseup" and "onclick" events, but BlotterObj.FireEvent "ondblclick"  do nothing.

how I could perform double click in this situaton? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote function for this:

```
Public Function FireDblClick(orObject)
    Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 'For Firefox
    orObject.FireEvent "ondblclick"
    Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
End Function
```